# Automation on Android Device

Tags: android, automation, ui-automation, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I am looking for a way to automatically open an application on Android. Something like QTP on windows. I read about quite a few testing tools for Android that need the phone to be connected to the laptop via USB. Is it possible to code an android application that can open another specific application on the device automatically?

I understand that if it is my application or an open source one, I can get the UI element and perform click or type into it automatically using code but how can I access UI elements of other apps on the device.

Example: My app should be able to open my phone keypad and type in a number or open an app like Truecaller and type into the textview on main screen? Something like web automation but for Android device. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intents:

```
//consider context as being the Context of your current app
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(PACKAGE_NAME);
context.startActivity(intent);
device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(PACKAGE_NAME)), 10000);  //this is a UiAutomator method to wait for the application to be started (or 10 seconds).
```

You can also use solo UiAutomator methods: open the apps menu, click on the app icon. You can see an example [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator)